# how to get the background process id from arr file and kill the process in android

Tags: android, multithreading, process

I'm using 3 party sdk and run a background service.

`com.other.sdk.connection.starttheservice(context);`

But im not able to kill that backgroundservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the killBackgroundProcesses() method of ActivityManager:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

or

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```